# The principal directions of curvature of the saddle surface z = xy

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I've been looking at a problem in Elementary Differential Geometry by Barrett O'Neill (Revised 2nd Edition), and Im having trouble confirming what the question asks is true.

The problem goes as follows (5.4.10):

"Show that the saddle surface z = xy the two vector fields

$$ ( \sqrt{1+x^2} \pm \sqrt{1+y^2}, y\sqrt{1+x^2} \pm x\sqrt{1+y^2}) $$

are principal at each point. Check that they are orthogonal and tangent to M."

The first issue I have is making sure that the 2 vector fields Im using are correct. I assume the author means the following 2 vector fields in $R^2$:

$$ ( \sqrt{1+x^2} + \sqrt{1+y^2}, y\sqrt{1+x^2} + x\sqrt{1+y^2}) \hspace{1cm} (1) $$ and
$$ ( \sqrt{1+x^2} - \sqrt{1+y^2}, y\sqrt{1+x^2} - x\sqrt{1+y^2}) \hspace{1cm} (2)$$

If I assume that the Monge Patch for this problem is $A: R^2 \mapsto M$ where $A(x,y) = (x,y,xy)$ then the tangent map of A $(A_{*})$ is:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
y & x  \\
\end{pmatrix}

and the Shaper operator, S, of M (where $S: R^2 \mapsto T_{p}M$) is:
$$ \frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-xy & 1+x^2  \\
1+y^2 & -xy  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I initially tried solving this out for the general case by showing that the vectors from (1) and (2) (which I will call $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ respectively) work, but wasnt able to show that $S(V_{1}) = k_{1}V_{1}$.

Instead I tried to see if any of this worked out at the origin, $(0,0)$.

This means that $V_{1} = (2,0)$, $V_2 = (0,0)$, the tangent map (in this case $R^2 \mapsto T_{(0,0)}(M)$) equals:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix}

And the Shape operator is:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}

However, with the above Shape operator, the eigen values are $\pm 1$ and the eigenvectors are $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ which are definitely not parallel to $V_1$ and $V_2$ as show above.

Is there a typo in the question? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It looks to me like a typo in the question. Consider, for example, what happens at the origin.

Comment: This is incorrect. See Example 6 on pp. 49-50 of my differential geometry text, (freely) linked in my profile.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Much appreciated! :)